# How to convert Datetime2 to DateTime in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I need to convert `datetime2` (getting data from SQL Server) to `datetime` (like current time) in ASP.NET.

I use this method but it is not working correctly

```
Convert.ToDateTime(messageVO.MDateTime).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd h:mm tt")
```

`messageVO.MDateTime` is getting from database.

How can I do this? Please help me.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot do a conversion since the implicit DateTime2 mapping to .NET data type is to System.DateTime (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb675168.aspx). Without seeing your class definition for the type of messageVO, I would expect MDateTime to be of DateTime data type (especially if you're using entity framework) as part of the mapping standards.